# What's the shortest way of writing "Hello World" in C++?

Tags: c++, io

I'm trying to create the shortest version of the "Hello World" program.
This is what I have so far.
Is there any shorter way to write it?

Edit: I use VS Code and Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 on Windows, if this information is helpful.

Edit 2: For those asking about

> "shortest version/way",

I meant the number of characters in the source code. Thank you.

```
#include<ios>
int main(){printf("Hello World");}
```

Comment: What do you mean shortest? Number of lines?

Comment: _" Is there any shorter way to write it?"_ Well, `int main(){std::cout << "Hello World";}` isn't actually less typing than the classic c hello world program.

Comment: `#include<ios>` is not portable. That doesn't count.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's strange. Mine works.